# Creating a backup of Amazon S3 tables | command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, command-line-interface, amazon-emr

I have some tables in my S3 bucket and I want to create a backup for them via the EMR command line.

Here is a breakdown of what I want to do

1. copy s3 objects into a backup S3 location
2. create metadata for the backup table (use DDL from the original table but read data  in from the backup S3 location)
3. validate row count between the main and the backup table

So far I have been able to write a script to copy objects from the main tables external location to the backup tables external location

```
backup table() {
db=${1}
table=${2}
s3_location=$(aws glue get-table --database-name $(db) --name $(table) --query "Table.StorageDescriptor.Location")
bash -c "aws s3 cp --recursive $s3_location ${s3_location}_bkp"
}
backup_table "database" "table"
```

I can't figure out how to access the main table's DDL in cli (`show create table db.table` in athena).

Will greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps: [SHOW CREATE TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-create-table.html)

Comment: want to access the DDL via cli not athena. `show create table` can't work.

Comment: Use [start-query-execution — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/start-query-execution.html) to send a query to Amazon Athena, then poll [get-query-results — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/get-query-results.html) to retrieve the results.